# From shapefiles to a database

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sql-server, well-known-text

I've previously converted simple shapefiles to WKT so that I can store them in RDMS that has spatial capabilities. I'm a new user to QGIS, which I'm using to browse a shapefile. But now I have a shapefile like this:

[image]

Not only are there polygons, but there are labels on those polygons. Really what I'd like is to strip off the polygons and save them with their associated label. So something like:

```
row1 ("POLYGON((1 1,5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1))) 'high'
row2 ("POLYGON((2 2,5 1,5 5,1 5,2 2))) 'medium'
row3 ("POLYGON((5 5,5 1,7 7,1 5,5 5))) 'high'
row3 ("POLYGON((8 8,5 1,5 5,1 7,8 8))) 'low'
```

I'm a little stumped at the best way to creatively slice up my shapefile, ideally by some of the attributes defined in the accompanying dbf file. Ideally I'd like to:

1. export, as WKT, all of the polygons with 'high'
2. export, as WKT, all of the polygons with 'low'

etc, etc.

Comment: Are you saying everything is stored in the shapefile and co already? There's no converter like `shp2pgsql` for sql-server? That would import the dbf as the table and add the geometry column from the shp.

Comment: is there any reason you converted to WKT from SHP before going to the RDMS? QGIS, for example can allow you to dump the SHP to SpatiaLite, for example, without going to WKT... maybe I'm not understanding the problem...